# How to achieve the map concept in C without using C++ STLs

Tags: c, dictionary, stl

In C++ `map` used to point the value with respect to the key.

How to achieve the same in C programming language *without* using C++ STL concepts

Comment: Consider using [uthash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) as explained in [looking-for-hash-table-c-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197825/looking-for-hash-table-c-library). This is a header only hash map implementation.

Comment: @pbn The `std::map` is ordered, so hashtable is not suitable if that is a requirement.

Comment: @user694733 Of course a hash table is ordered, just not necessarily in a sequential way (which shouldn't matter). What makes you think that std::map is sequentially ordered internally?

Comment: @Lundin `std::map`, `std::set`, `std::multimap`, and `std::multiset` are all required to be ordered by non-decreasing key, from the iterator sequence perspective. (Which is why the C++11 types with O(1) average time operations are called `unordered_`*.)

Comment: @aschepler You can get that with a hashtable too, depending on the hash function and the method used for "chaining". Every item in the hashtable could be some form of BST, for example.

Comment: In the Unix/Linux world you have the functions `hcreate`, `hsearch` and `hdestroy` (or `tsearch` and alii if order matters) that are declared conforming to  X/Open Portability Guide Issue 4, Version 2 (XPG4.2). If you need larger portability (Windows) googling for *c hashmap* of *b btree* should give a pockeful of implementations that you can use directly or read as examples if you decide to roll your own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you really need to do is define a `struct` that contains at least members for your key and value, and then define a container that can hold multiple of that struct.  The container just needs to support three basic operations: Insert, Remove, and Find.

Almost any sort of [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) will do, but with different tradeoffs between easy implementation and efficiency.  Some of the most likely options are:

- **An array or linked list**: If you know there will never be a large amount of data and efficiency isn't really a concern, you could just go simple.  The Find operation can just be a simple linear search.
- **A sorted array**: You could also choose to keep a simple array sorted every time you Insert or Remove an entry.  This lets the Find algorithm use a binary search, and might be appropriate if Find will be needed much more often than Insert or Remove.
- **A [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)**: If you want the O(log N) Insert/Remove/Find efficiency performance provided by C++'s `std::map` for large data sets, a red-black tree is a good choice.  This also guarantees the elements are sorted by key, which is useful if you need to deal with subranges of the data.
- **A [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)**: C++11 introduced `std::unordered_map`, and if you can find or produce a hash function for your key type, you can imitate it in C by implementing a hash table. This data structure has O(1) average case Insert/Remove/Find, but O(N) worst case Insert/Remove/Find. The entries are not sorted.

Implementing a red-black tree or hash table can be a bit tricky, but there are a number of free implementations available that you could find and use.

Comment: Small addition to sorted array option: the C standard library offers `bsearch` and `qsort` functions, which is only help that standard library offers for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such data structure available from the standard C library. You need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to implement a dictionary (it is usually an RB-tree in case of `std::map`) on your own, or use any of the libraries that provides one.